# htaccess working for first rule but not second one

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have 2 pages Advertisement.php and Gidc.php and they work if they have user="some value"
For example:

```
example.com/advertisement_final_page.php?user=sumeet
```

and

```
example.com/gidc_final_page.php?user=nikhil
```

I want code for htaccess to redirects it to above pages:

```
example.com/sumeet
```

and

```
example.com/nikhil
```

**My database is:**

**id**   1

**Type** Advertisement

**user** sumeet

**contact**  651651

**owner**    Sumeet Patel

**website**  asdfkjh.com

**email**    sdfjh@skdj.com

**address**  skjdf, sd, sdh

**id**   2

**Type** Gidc

**user** nikhil

**contact**  651651

**owner**    Nikhil Patel

**website**  sadfjh.com

**email**    sdf@sdhf.com

**address**  skjdf, sd, sdh

**My htaccess rules:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ advertisement_final_page.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ gidc_final_page.php?user=$1
```

But by above codes it reach to advertisement_final_page.php page.
Like if I enter

```
example.com/nikhil
```

it redirects to

```
example.com/advertisement_final_page.php?user=nikhil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns in your rules seem to be identical. The RewriteEngine will match the first rule it can, in this case the first.

You should probably write a controller file that you redirect all your requests to. Then read the required user from `$_GET['user']`, read the user's data from your database and redirect/include the appropriate PHP file based on the user's `Type`.

Comment: exactly i use GET to check user="" in table and then only page loads. but if anyone writes example.com/nikhil it should go to example.com/gidc_final_page.php?user=nikhil and if anyone writes example.com/sumeet then it should go to example.com/advertisement_final_page.php?user=sumeet

Answer (score 1):

Your second match is processed ONLY IF the previous matches are wrong. In this case, both are same, and the first one is TRUE always. So, `advertisement_final_page.php?user=nikhil` is loaded, and remaining lines are skipped.

You can tell what you really want to achieve, and let's guide you. :-)

**------------------------Edit------------------------**

As per your need, you can do the following:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ redirect.php?user=$1`

Inside the redirect.php, you can write:

```
$u = $GET['user'];

if( $u == 'sumeet'){
   header('location: advertisement_final_page.php?user=sumeet');
} else if ( $u == 'nikhil') {
   header('location: gidc_final_page.php?user=nikhil');
}
```

**But please understand that this code is not a standard one.** For making this code better one, you need to check for `$user` in a database, then redirect accordingly, rather than using `if()` to compare all the names.

For that purpose you can use of a table, like this one:

```
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|  username  |             redirect_url              |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|   nikhil   |       gidc_final_page.php?user=       |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|   sumeet   |  advertisement_final_page.php?user=   |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|    alice   |       gidc_final_page.php?user=       |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|     ....   |                  ....                 |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
```

I hope this will help you out :-)

Comment: advertisement_final_page.php and gidc_final_page.php are 2 different pages which takes information from same table. if user variable is set in link then it checks from table and fetch the data on the basis of type column. now if anyone writes example.com/nikhil it should go to example.com/gidc_final_page.php?user=nikhil and if anyone writes example.com/sumeet then it should go to example.com/advertisement_final_page.php?user=sumeet